# How to add an arbitrary script hook before appEngine compileJava task is executed

Tags: google-app-engine, android-studio, gradle

I am building a Google App Engine (GAE) project under Android Studio. I want to be able to have different "buildTypes" similar to how one can do for an android app project, however this is not supported by the appEngine Gradle plugin (see https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin/issues/177). As a workaround, I want to run some kind of script (e.g.: ant, bash, or similar), to do some arbitrary command prior to the build, so that I can copy or rename the right source files into place for the build. Unfortunately, being somewhat unfamiliar with Gradle, I am at a loss of how to do that. I've been reading the Gradle documentation but have been unable to discover how to add a hook before the :backend:compileJava task is executed. Can anyone explain how I might be able to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't solved this yet

You can have any task depend on any other :

```
task myPrecompileTask {
  doLast {
    // execute some code here
  }
}

compileJava.dependsOn myPrecompileTask
```

That will force any call to compileJava to call myPrecomileTask first.